# How to create a Tamper Evident Seals or Signature for HTML a Document

Tags: html, encryption, hash, md5, hmac

I want to replace some PDF files with more accessible self contained HTML documents.

Images can be encoded using Data URI
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

I need to ensure the documents have not been tempered with For legal reasons
and if possible verify authenticity.

These documents are "public" so they don't need to be "secure" they need a 
tamper proof "seal" or signature which can easily show if a file has been altered.

The file will normally remain on the clients machine for their records.

I was contemplating using a MD5 hash, with my own long salt key word , that 
only I know.  The page will be saved with the hash appended to the file.

To check the page remove the last line and check the hash.

Any suggestions / links for further reading:

- for simple ways to  to create a secure seal workable solution
- is an MD5 Hash suitable or are there better algorithms.
- e.g HMAC-MD5 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code
- how much more complicated would it be to use using a public / private key system

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 is not good enough anymore. Use HMAC-SHA256 or better. Potentially use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 to make it even more improbably to forge the MAC.

You could of course use public key signature algorithm like RSA, but you've got to ask yourself the following. If you will be the only one who needs to verify the signature, then you don't need the additional overhead of RSA and you can safely stick to HMAC. Because the problem with HMAC is that the salt has to be known to the "signing" and the "verifying" party.